# Rate of convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^k { k \choose i} a_{n,p}(i)(-p)^{k-i}\to 0$ where $a_{n,p}(i)= \prod_{r=0}^{i-1} \frac{np+r}{n+1+r}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the following binomial sum: fix $p \in (0,1)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^k  { k \choose i} a_{n,p}(i)(-p)^{k-i}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
a_{n,p}(i)= \prod_{r=0}^{i-1} \frac{np+r}{n+1+r}
\end{align}
with $a_{n,p}(0)=1$.

We are interested in showing at what rate the sum goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.  That is we are interested in characterizing $d$ and $c$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}  n^d \sum_{i=0}^k  { k \choose i} a_{n,p}(i)(-p)^{k-i}=c
\end{align}

**Question:** For every $p \in (0,1)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ determine $d$ and $c$.

My guess is that  $d=k/2$ but I am not sure what $c$ is.

**What did I do:**  Showing that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{i=0}^k  { k \choose i} a_{n,p}(i)(-p)^{k-i}=0
\end{align}
is fairly easy since
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n,p}(i)=p^{i}
\end{align}

Thus, by using this and the binomial theorem,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{i=0}^k  { k \choose i} a_{n,p}(i)(-p)^{k-i}= \sum_{i=0}^k  { k \choose i} p^i (-p)^{k-i}= (p-p)^k=0
\end{align}

However, I am not even sure how to approach on how to find the rate

Comment: The sum $S$ is equal to
$$p^{p n + k} q^{q n + k + 1} k! n! \left(
 \frac {(-1)^k}  {(p n + k)! (q n)!}
  {_2 F_1}(k + 1, n + k + 1; p n + k + 1; p) + \\
 \frac 1 {(p n - 1)! (q n + k + 1)!}
  {_2 F_1}(k + 1, n + k + 1; q n + k + 2; q) \right),$$
where $q = 1 - p$. Applying Laplace's method to the Euler integral representation of ${_2 F_1}$ gives
$$S = \frac 1 {6 \sqrt \pi} \left( \frac {2 p q} n \right)^{k/2}
 \left( 3 ((-1)^k + 1) \left( \frac {k - 1} 2 \right)! + \\
  ((-1)^k - 1) ((p - q) k + p + 1) \left( \frac k 2 \right)!
   \sqrt {\frac 2 {p q n}} + o(n^{-1/2}) \right).$$

Comment: Can you add this as an answer with more details?  For example, can you add how you got the first part and house applied Laplace method

Comment: The identity
$$S =
\frac {n! (p n + k - 1)!} {(n + k)! (p n - 1)!}
 \hspace {1.5 px} {_2 F_1}(-k, -n - k; - p n - k + 1; p)$$
can be verified directly by comparing terms of two finite sums. Then we convert ${_2 F_1}(a, b; c; z)$ to a combination of ${_2 F_1}(1 - a, 1 - b; 2 - c; z)$ and ${_2 F_1}(1 - a, 1 - b; 1 - a - b + c; 1 - z)$ to make all the parameters positive. To apply Laplace's method, start by writing the integrands as $f(t) e^{n \phi(t)}$.